# Faster way to hide empty rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to hide all rows where the *value* of the cell in Column A is blank (i.e. empty). I was trying to use the following code:

```
Range("A7:A117").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

However, every cell in Column A has a `VLOOKUP` formula and the `xlCellTypeBlanks` considers a cell with a formula, but no value, *not* to be blank.

So I tried using the following code, but it is extremely slow.

```
For i = 17 To 117
  If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

How do I speed it up?

Comment: Have you turned screen update off? I found that using a for loop was plenty fast enough if you set `application.screenupdating = false` before you run it and then `application.screenupdating = True` afterwards. The slow part for me was updating the screen after every row was changes

Comment: I like `IsEmpty` as in `If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)) Then`

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you try AutoFilter:

```
Range("A7:A117").AutoFilter 1, "<>", , , False
```

Comment: + 1 Yup `Autofilter` is the faster way than looping :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not the for loop that is slow it is that you are updating the screen everytime something changes (this uses a fair bit of processing power and thus slows everything down). if you turn screen updating off before you hide the rows then turn it back on after it will only update once and the script will run much much faster. I tried it with 100 rows and it was almost instant.

```
Sub hideEmptyRows()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To 117
  If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: you can make it even faster by writing the blank cells to a range (using Union) inside the loop and only calling one `EntireRow.Hidden` call against the concatenated range.

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("A7:A117").AutoFilter 1, "<>", , , False
```

It hides empty cells but if you try to unhide with mouse you cannot

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: look at L42's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer without Autofilter :

```
Dim totalRange As Range
ActiveSheet.Range("A17:A117").Hidde = false


For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A17:A117")
   If cell = "" And totalRange Is Nothing Then
        Set totalRange = cell
   ElseIf cell = "" Then
        Set totalRange = Application.union(totalRange, cell)
   End If
Next

If Not totalRange Is Nothing Then
    totalRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```