# Hide Rows when cell is empty excel (faster way)

Tags: vba, excel

I had a look at some articles and suggestions and came up with a solution for my problem.

The article [Faster way to hide empty rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078437/faster-way-to-hide-empty-rows) suggested to use to toggle `Application.ScreenUpdating` before the loop to false and after to true. It sped up the script a little but for 10.000 rows it still takes quite some time.

**Requirements:**

If the first cell in the row is empty, hide the complete row
it needs to be backwards compatible to other excel versions than 2013

**Current working solution for excel 2013**

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Dim s As String
 For i = 1 To range("A1:A10000").Count
     s = i & ":" & i
     If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
         Rows(s).Select
         Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
 Next
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Unfortunately I don't know how much data in the sheet is, it can contain less than 10.000 which i used in my example or even more. When i run the script it works fine, but takes quite a while for 10.000 rows and ages for all cells in the sheet.

The macro would run on automatically when the workbook is loaded (not sure yet how to do that either haha)

Comment: There's an answer with 3 upvotes in that same link you posted to which provides the code for using autofilter which is much faster

Comment: @tigeravatar oh ok thanks, i didn't see that... i wished there was bit more explanation to it. I'll try to re-write it for my case and if the results are what i'm looking for. Thanks again, will get back to it once i have tried it.

Comment: Ok, this one can be closed. I used the auto filter suggestion described in the post i mentioned in my problem. worked fine for me `Range("A1:A10000").AutoFilter 1, "<>", , , False`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Faster way to hide empty rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078437/faster-way-to-hide-empty-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comments and in this post: [Faster way to hide empty rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078437/faster-way-to-hide-empty-rows)
and thanks to @tigeravatar for pointing it out. I used the following code which worked in my scenario:

```
Range("A1:A10000").AutoFilter 1, "<>", , , False
```

Comment: How do i integrate this to my code? This is my current code: `Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Dim xRg As Range
    For Each xRg In Range("D22:D728")
        If xRg.Value = "" Then
            xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = True

        Else
            xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next xRg
End Sub`

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim rngBlnk As Range

On Error Resume Next 'in case no blanks are present...
Set rngBlnk = Range("A1:A100000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rngBlnk Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print rngBlnk.Address()
    rngBlnk.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The select process takes time, and there is no need to select the row before hiding the row. Try the variation below...

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim s As String
For i = 1 To range("A1:A10000").Count
    s = i & ":" & i
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
         Rows(s).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```