# Hide rows based on the date

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to keep the last 365 days visible in a micro tracking worksheet. As a new date gets inputted it would hide the first visible entry on the sheet so that only 365 cells are constantly displayed with the newest date at the bottom(ex Jan 15, 2015) and the oldest date at the top(Jan 15, 2014). When the user inputs `Jan 16, 2015` it would hide `Jan 15, 2014` so that the first entry is now `Jan 16, 2014`, and so on.

It has probably been about 15 years since I last used VBA but currently the code shown below will hide row 3 (where the first date and data is entered) but after that I can't get it to then hide row 4 once row 369 has text entered. Some insight into what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

I would also assume that as this sheet became progressively larger it would start to slow down in opening or running smoothly so I would have to start fresh unless there is a way to make sure it always stays fast.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    i = 3
    j = 368
    If Cells(j, j) = "" Then
        Rows(i).Hidden = True
    End If
    i = i + 1
    j = j + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: what column do you have the dates in?

Comment: Column A. Sorry for not being specific about it :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub HideRows()
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    lngLastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    If lngLastRow < 365 Then End
    Rows(lngLastRow - 365).Hidden = True
End Sub
```

This is assuming that:

1. you are working in a sheet named "Sheet1" (if not, change the name in line 3 of the code accordingly)
2. the dates are in column A and start in row 1 (even the hidden ones). If the dates are in a different column, then change the second number in the `cells(1, 1)` statement to the number of the row. And if the dates do not start in row 1, change the first number of the `cells(1, 1)` statement to the row number of the first date.

And if you want to keep the row for the day exactly one year ago (as in, keep 1-15-14 on 1-15-15), you may need to change `365` in line 5 of the code to `366`. This code also assumes that all other rows besides the one that was visible yesterday but doesn't need to be today are already hidden.

Comment: Thanks for that. I should have gone home 30 minutes ago so I will try this out tomorrow and let you know how it worked.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Yours does work but will just need some modification I think. Any days there are blanks because we didnt run that day it doesnt count and just hides the row regardless of the actual day so eventually it would be getting messed up but it does work nicely for what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a completely different approach, but might suit you better in the long run.

Instead of hiding the rows to view what you are interested in.  This approach uses two sheets.

1. Log Sheet: Contains all days
2. Report Sheet: Re-fills with only the last 365 days.

**Setup Involved:**

- Set a second sheet up for your report, and give it the same headers as your Log Sheet.
- Place the code provided in a module
- If you want, you can add a workbook event so when the workbook opens, you can call this sub and have it update itself, or attach it to a hotkey or button.

This gives you plenty of room to create new formulas and charts to work over the set range of the report sheet.  You can hide the Log Sheet.

**Code:**

```
Sub lastYearReportFill()

Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, lRow As Long, rRow As Long
Dim log As String, report As String
Dim today As Date, tempDate As Date
Dim daysTest As Long

log = "Log"             'Name your worksheets here
report = "Report"
today = Now

lastRow = Sheets(log).Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
lastCol = Sheets(log).Cells(2, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column   'Using Header Row

    For lRow = 3 To lastRow
        tempDate = Sheets(log).Cells(lRow, 1)
        daysTest = DateDiff("d", tempDate , today)
        If daysTest = 365 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next lRow

    For rRow = 3 To 368
        For lCol = 1 To lastCol
            Sheets(report).Cells(rRow, lCol).Value = Sheets(log).Cells(lRow, lCol).Value
        Next lCol
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next rRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi peege, 
would it be possible to grab info from 2 different sheets to combine them into the report sheet? I have a 2014 sheet and now a 2015 sheet that we have started to fill in. Could it grab 2014, fill it into the report and then grab 2015 and fill it in as well?
I would put this in a button to limit how long the sheet hangs for but as each new report is run it would delete the oldest entry and add the newest?

Comment: Yes, it's possible (although a different question).  I would just combine the two into one big log file, and let the report grab the last 365 days. I wouldn't write code for that, since it's a one time move.  Just copy all the records from 2015 and put them after the 2014 records.  As long as you refer to that sheet with all the records as the log sheet in the code above, it will show you the last 365, even though the years are separate.

Comment: Thanks peege. I will try to play around with it a little and see if I can get it to grab from the 2 different sheets myself. My boss wants a running tally so that we always see the most recent 365 days so I will try to modify the code enough to do what he wants. Thanks for the starting base though.

Comment: Cant edit lol but your way is easier :) I will paste into a large file and go from there. Will have to modify slightly since people will sometimes enter into the same date multiple times if they are reporting on different issues on the same day but it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned with speed, use *Range AutoFilter Method* which I answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078437/faster-way-to-hide-empty-rows/24078596#24078596).
Applying it to your case:

```
Private Sub UpdateVisibleDates(sh As Worksheet, drng As Range)
    With sh
        Dim latest As Date
        latest = .Range("A:A").Find("*", .Range("A1"), , , , xlPrevious).Value2
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        drng.AutoFilter 1, ">" & (latest - 365), xlAnd, "<=" & latest, False
    End With
End Sub
```

Then just call it in your *Worksheet_Change Event*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo halt
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim r As Range
        Set r = Me.Range("A1:A" & Me.Range("A:A") _
            .Find("*", Me.Range("A1"), , , , xlPrevious).Row)
        UpdateVisibleDates Me, r
    End If
forward:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
halt:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
        Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume forward
End Sub
```

This is considering you have a complete date in Column A and your input doesn't skip dates.
But regardless, it will still hide dates not within the 365 date difference of the last entered date. HTH.